# Submit app to Play store and Itunes Connect programmatically

Tags: android, ios, api, google-play, app-store

I'm working on an app generator and I would like to know if someone have any experience about submitting to different app stores through api/curl.

I've found that :

- For Android : https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/
- For iOS : https://github.com/fastlane/itc-api-docs

The goal is to submit apk/ipa, stores assets, descriptions, etc.

And maybe if it's possible to have the current approval process status ?

If anyone can help.

Thanks !

Comment: It seems Google Play Developer API only allows you to programmatically manage your Apps after you have created a new app in Play Publisher Dashboard. Have you come to any solution?

Answer (score 1):

**Google Play Developer Publishing API** allows you to automate frequent tasks having to do with app production and distribution. This provides functions similar to those available to a developer through the Developer Console, such as:

- Uploading new versions of an app
- Releasing apps, by assigning APKs to various Tracks (alpha, beta, staged rollout, or production)
- Creating and modifying Google Play Store listings, including localized text and graphics and multi-device screenshots

Reference: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher

Comment: Already read that. I'm looking for someone who have experienced that in the two stores !

Comment: Have you tried to use the iTunes Transporter to upload your app to iTunes Connect? Check out the source code of deliver on GitHub: https://github.com/KrauseFx/deliver/blob/master/lib/deliver/itunes_transporter.rb. You can then use deliver to automatically upload new updates to the App Store: https://github.com/KrauseFx/deliver/.